# How to find an unknown string in a file, in the format x.xx where each x is a number?

Tags: powershell

So i have a PS script that takes in a $FilePath paramater, then it runs this code

```
if (findstr /c:"Lunar Magic Version" $FilePath) {echo "This ROM has been edited with Lunar Magic" $Version} else {echo "This ROM has not been edited by lunar magic"}
```

But before that whole thing $Version is set to "0.00".
Instead i want it to set $Version to a string that is found just after the "Lunar Magic Version" text in a file,the string is in the format x.xx where each x is a number but i dont know how to find that
(no i cant just cat the line that "Lunar Magic Version" is on because the entire file is technically a single, extremly long string)

Sorry if my question is very specific or dumb, im very new to powershell TBH

Comment: You could do a regex match like `if((GC $FilePath|?{$_ -match "Lunar Magic Version (\d\.\d\d)"})){"This ROM has been edited with Lunar Magic $($Matches[1])"} else {echo "This ROM has not been edited by lunar magic"}`

Comment: Thx @TheMadTechnician that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a regex match like `if((GC $FilePath|?{$_ -match "Lunar Magic Version (\d\.\d\d)"})){"This ROM has been edited with Lunar Magic $($Matches[1])"} else {echo "This ROM has not been edited by lunar magic"}"` – TheMadTechnician